# downgrading net framework from 4 to 2

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

We upgraded the .net framework to 4.0 for application I was working on but since the server which the app is running is not ready yet for 4.0, the client wanted the application still to run on framework 2.0.

After switching the framework back to 2.0 I got a lot of errors related to ajaxcontroltoolkit. You can check the screenshot at this page: http://gyazo.com/a95f0895f77f7c2d330f5a7622d22481.png?1345125742.

I found one ajaxcontroltoolkit from this website http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/11121, "AjaxControlToolkit-NoSource.zip" which I thought will solve the errors but that didn't help.

I would like to know what do I need to do to fix this error.

Comment: The AjaxControlToolkit has not supported .NET 2.0 for a long time. You will probably spend more effort trying to fix your application to work in .NET 2.0 than convincing your client to just install .NET 4.

Comment: Does `hg revert --all` and `del *.orig /s` count as a fix?